# Django, PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

after starting clean project bases on these packages (basically my requirements.txt):

```
Django>=1.7, <1.8
psycopg2
aldjemy
```

My `python manage.py migrate` raise errors:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .orm import prepare_models
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/orm.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .core import get_tables, get_engine, Cache
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/core.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .table import generate_tables
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/table.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.loading import AppCache
ImportError: cannot import name 'AppCache'
(env)3-AM-OSX:bank stay-wide-awake$ python manage.py makemigrations accounts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .orm import prepare_models
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/orm.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .core import get_tables, get_engine, Cache
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/core.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .table import generate_tables
  File "/Users/stay-wide-awake/web/bank/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aldjemy/table.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.loading import AppCache
ImportError: cannot import name 'AppCache'
```

It doesn't matter what database i use in my configuration - postgresql or sqlite, so i figure out that SQLAlchemy is causing extension.  But I cant figure out where is the problem spot. Can you help?

Also i use Python3.4, as u can see from logs.

Answer (score 0):

Installing directly from [repository](http://github.com/mathieurodic/aldjemy) helps!